# Remove hashtag from URL after action

Tags: jquery

I have a hashtag in the URL to trigger a specific action with a hashtag sniffer.

But when the action is complete, and the page reloads, it is loading with the hashtag still.  Any idea on how to remove the hashtag when the page refreshes?

Comment: Your chances of getting an answer will greatly increase if you show what you have attempted, or at least your code...

Comment: It's not a "hashtag", it's a fragment identifier. I will stab anyone using the word "hashtag" outside of a social-network context in the face with a rusty spork.

Comment: @Dai, it might not be a "hashtag", but it is a "hash".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
```

If that doesn't reload the page then after that just do:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Even worse, the page is loading infinitely when i add the second line